# Visualforce Table Grouping

Tags: visualforce, controller

I cant seem to get the table to be grouped by the ownerID and Sum the Amount withoutadjustments

Controller

```
public class ForecastListController {

private String GroupParameter = 'Ownerid';

public List<ForecastingItem> getForecastingItem() {

List<ForecastingItem> results = Database.query('SELECT id, SUM(AmountWithoutAdjustments), Ownerid, PeriodID, ProductFamily ' + 'FROM ForecastingItem ' + 'Group BY ' + GroupParameter);

return results;}

}
```

VF Page

```
<apex:page controller="ForecastListController">


<apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!ForecastingItem}" var="FI">
         <apex:column value="{!FI.id}"/>
         <apex:column value="{!FI.ownerid}"/>
         <apex:column value="{!FI.PeriodId}"/>
         <apex:column value="{!FI.ProductFamily}"/>
         <apex:column value="{!FI.AmountWithoutAdjustments}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>

</apex:page>
```

Thank you

Comment: this will give you error. aggregate query return aggregate result not the list of ForecastingItem

Comment: How can i get the list and the do the grouping within it?

Comment: if you use aggregate query based on ownerId and calculate the amount then you can't show the other fields like id, productfamily and AmountWithoutAdjustments fields

Comment: Ok, Is there a way to do what im looking at? just group the Forecast items by the owner and show the amounts?

Comment: yeah you can show ownerId and total amounts related to each owner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you should return aggregate result from your method

```
public class ForecastListController {

    private String GroupParameter = 'Ownerid';

        public List<AggregateResult> getForecastingItem() {

            List<AggregateResult> results = Database.query('SELECT  SUM(AmountWithoutAdjustments) total, Ownerid FROM ForecastingItem ' + 
                                                            ' Group BY ' + GroupParameter);

            return results;
        }
    }
```

And in VF page use like below

```
<apex:page controller="ForecastListController">
<apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!ForecastingItem}" var="FI">

         <apex:column value="{!FI['total']}"/>
         <apex:column value="{!FI['Ownerid']}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Thank you, so there is no way to display the owner. My aim was eventually to have this to be displayed per forecast owner and  grouped by product family and bucketed in correct forecast periods. If this isnt possible i will have to look at alternatives

Comment: @user37980 you have ownerId in VF page. You can use another map to get the ower name as well

Comment: Ok thanks i will have a look into how to do this, sorry if these are silly questions this is quite new to us

Comment: @user37980 yeah no problem

Comment: last question just to point in the right direction, where would i have to use the map to get this to work? thank you so much for your help

Comment: @user37980 you can create a separate map to store the user id and user Name. Now in VF page `{!FI['Ownerid']}` this will give you the Id of user and you can get the user name using this id from newly created map

Comment: Thank you for this, think this may be beyond my skill will have to get it written for us, thank you for improving my understanding much apprecitated

Comment: is there any documentation i can read around this? i cant seem to find the right thing

Comment: @user37980 if you are facing issue with implementation then you can ask a new question. I am not if there is any documentation for this

Answer (score 0):

Your approach towards aggregate result is wrong.
You cant have the id in the query.Also please check periodid,productfamily have only one value when grouped by owner id.Please return a list of aggregateResults rather than returning list,It will result in error
Please do the following,

```
  List<AggregateResult> ForecastingItem= Database.query('SELECT id, SUM(AmountWithoutAdjustments) total, Ownerid, PeriodID, ProductFamily ' + 'FROM ForecastingItem ' + 'Group BY ' + GroupParameter);
```

Also in the visualforce page

```
<apex:column value="{!FI.total}"/>
```

You can also refer to the below url for further information:

http://sfdcintegration.blogspot.in/2014/03/displaying-aggregateresult-on.html
http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/04/12/using-aggregateresult-in-salesforce-com-soql/